# Google cloud compute startup script ignored with no logging

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a standard Debian 8.9 instance on google cloud compute (GCE) where my startup script is ignored.

In the custom metadata field, for startup-script, I am trying to run an Rscript (which is used for batch execution of R files), followed by a system shutdown, with the following:

```
#! /bin/bash
sudo /usr/bin/Rscript /home/myuser/launch_script.R
sudo shutdown -h now
```

Starting the instance is immediately followed by a shutdown and the Rscript is ignored. Removing the last line to shutdown causes the GCE instance to start, but the Rscript to be ignored. Running just "sudo /usr/bin/Rscript /home/myuser/launch_script.R" from the terminal results in the script being run. It has a chmod of 755, so I don't think this is a permissions issue.

In addition to this problem, I have read elsewhere that logging should happen in /var/log/, but there is nothing there. Instead, I have a bunch of log files (that only contain the start-up script and nothing else) in the root of my instance:

[image: Screenshot of filesystem root]

Answer (score 3):

I got in touch with Google cloud support, who gave the following response:

- script definition is kept under /var/run/google.startup.script
- If the script does not run initially, you can force it manually with : $ sudo google_metadata_script_runner --script-type startup # for Debian, or # sudo /usr/share/google/run-startup-scripts # on Ubuntu and older images

I'm posting this information here, because it is not in their documentation (as of August 2017). I'm not sure how helpful it is, since the google.startup.script didn't exist in my case (using the latest Debian image on GCE), but I did run the other commands.

However, I think my main issues were:

1. I was using autossh to connect to a remote database. The startup-script was running before autossh. Building a 40 second delay into the script and running the script as a user (not sudo-type root) seems to have solved this problem for now. Autossh was being run as the main user, which I think gets loaded before lower-privilege user-defined scripts get loaded.
2. I was using some gcloud commands from the user account which had its own authentication issues. Running gcloud auth login as the user and ensuring correct permissions on my private key solved this.

Always remember to check the messages and syslog files in /var/log for troubleshooting. This allowed me to see the order of things being loaded at system-boot.

Comment: 3 Years later this helped me complete a part of homework assignment. who says we dont solve homework on SO